# Having trouble connecting EJS form with MONGODB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am having trouble and wrapping my head around how I can connect my front end in ejs and submitting a form that will send information to the back end.

Right now I have a file that is called server.js
which renders all my ejs pages and connects to the database. The code is below

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

//importing routes
const routes = require("./middleware/routes");

//puts requests into req.body
app.use(express.json());

//configures the middleware in routes
app.use(routes);

//connecting to mongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, () => console.log("data connected"));

//Using ejs syntax
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
 res.render("login.ejs");
});
app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
 res.render("register.ejs");
});

//Listening to incoming requests
const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**I also have a routes file that is below**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userControllers = require("../controllers/userControllers");

router.get("/getall", userControllers.getAllUsers);
router.post("/register", userControllers.createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

The code below is my function that should create a new user and would send it to my database. It works with postman, but I can't seem to figure out how to bridge the two concepts.

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await User.create({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    res.json(newUser);

  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

I am not really sure how to implement the form such that when I click the button it sends a request to my database. So far I have the code below for the register base that in theory I want it to send information to the database. I've tried looking at various resources online, but no one seems to have another file, instead they seem to all just work in the server file. However, I know it's best to keep it seperate, but I'm just not sure how I would implement it.

```
<form action="/register">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="username" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
<a href="/login">login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <form action="/register">
> ```

You have no `method` attribute, so the form is going to make a GET request. This encodes the data in the query string of the URL, **not** in the request body.

While you could read the data from there, you shouldn't submit credentials through URLs. Change it to:

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
```

---

> ```
> //puts requests into req.body
> app.use(express.json());
> ```

You need a body parsing middleware that supports the data format being POSTed.

Forms POST data using the urlencoded format (unless [you change it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype)), not JSON.

You need to use [middleware that matches](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded).

Comment: Hello, I read through the documentation you linked. Based off what you linkedin, I should change it to app.use(express.urlencoded()) instead? If that were the case, I would also have to change 

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = await User.create({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    res.json(newUser);

  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
};
``` 
res.send(newUser); 
```
instead?

Comment: "I should change it to app.use(express.urlencoded()) instead?" — Yes.

Comment: "If that were the case, I would also have to change ``` exports.createUser" — Why? (And I can't tell how you are proposing changing it because that code has been smeared all over the comment in a right mess)

Comment: Hello, sorry to simplify I would have to a specific line that says res.json(newUser) to res.send(newUser). Though I just tried it and for some reason it still doesn't seem to be sending it to my mongodb database. All it does is change my html page to the object.

Comment: `res.send()` and `res.json()` are how you send a response to the client, not to Mongodb. It would make sense to replace `res.json()` with something that sends an HTML document instead `res.send(a_user_object)` wouldn't do that.

Comment: If the user isn't being created then you'd need to do some debugging. e.g. log `req.body` to make sure the middleware is set up correct and do whatever checking you need to do to Mongodb to handle "duplicate user" errors and the like.

Comment: Hmm, but when I tried with POSTMAN and I sent http requests, it shows up on my mongodb atlas. So I think there is a gap in my understanding of what is actually happening.

Comment: OH, I think my atlas was bugging out, it added to my mongo db database. Res.json() works. But could you please explain by what you mean when you say "it would make sense to replace res.json() with something that sends an html document instead). I logged console.log(req.body) in that specific function and when I clicked submitted it did output a json object of what I inputted everything looks good so I just refreshed my atlas. thank you!!!

Comment: When you submit a form, the browser displays what it gets back from the server. A webpage is a much nicer thing to show the user than a JSON text.

Comment: Okay, so my understanding is that the res.send() sends it to the client which in this case is the html page? I think my understanding of http requests is a bit weak, thank you so much for helping me figuring out what I should work on. 

Is it possible to implement something that says "account created" and then ultimately redirects them to my login page. So far I just have a res.redirect() that redirects them to my login page instantly, but I want a message that says that an account has been created. Would I be doing that in EJS?

I am going to bed now as its 3am, but I will read in morning

Comment: We're getting *way* beyond the scope of this question. Try reading the documentation, having a go, and asking a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you! In the question that I asked previously, would the documentation just be express documentation or mongoDB? I'm still new to this. In other words, where should I be reading that shows me the relationship between various frameworks like express and mongo.